# PHP Try / Catch error trapping in Twilio question

Tags: php, twilio

New Twilio user here.  I am confused a bit on the whole concept of Twilio calls to their API in an interactive PHP Web app.  Unlike other API's I have used in the past, it seems like there is no built-in error handling on API calls.  It seems like all failed calls return a PHP "Fatal Error" halting execution.

Q1: So, does every single API call for Twilio need to be surrounded by a TRY/CATCH in order to handle any type of error that might occur?

For example, I was testing phone number formatting and validation with an intentionally bad phone number (which so many of our client's have in their databases):

```
$phone_number = $twilio->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers("(222) 123-124")
                                    ->fetch(["countryCode" => "US"]);
```

And get a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 404] Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /PhoneNumbers/...
```

If I add a try/catch I still get a pretty vague response:

```
20404 : [HTTP 404] Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /PhoneNumbers/+(222) 123-124 was not found
```

Q2: Is this the best response I can get from a bad phone number?  a 20404 error unable to fetch a record, the requested resource was not found?  Why not just respond with "bad phone number" or something?  Maybe I am using the wrong call type for validating a phone number?  Any advice appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with version 1 of the API, rather version 2. While it works in a similar way by using a try/catch block to handle exceptions, it provides two properties on the response object, `valid` and `validationErrors`, which might be of help.

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
$dotenv->required(['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID', 'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']);

use Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid = $_ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"];
$token = $_ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"];
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

try {
    $phoneNumber = $twilio
        ->lookups
        ->v2
        ->phoneNumbers("(222) 123-124")
        ->fetch(["countryCode" => "US"]);

    if (! $phoneNumber->valid) {
        var_dump($phoneNumber->validationErrors);
    }
} catch (TwilioException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

`valid` indicates if a phone number provided was valid. `validationErrors`, while not always returned (and not *the* most helpful) contains reasons why a phone number was considered invalid. The values that it may contain are `TOO_SHORT`, `TOO_LONG`, `INVALID_BUT_POSSIBLE`, `INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE`, `INVALID_LENGTH`, `NOT_A_NUMBER`. Perhaps this might be what you're looking for.